# ImageList_LoadImage doesn't find bitmap

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap

Trying to load a bitmap using ImageList_LoadImage but fails with `ErrorCode 1814 - Could not find resource`
However these lines preceeding it work

```
HRSRC myResource = FindResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP1), RT_BITMAP);
auto imageResDataHandle = LoadResource(NULL, myResource);
TRACE("Error %d", GetLastError()); // All OK

auto hImageList = ::ImageList_LoadImage(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP1), 16, 2, CLR_DEFAULT, IMAGE_BITMAP, 0); 
TRACE("Error %d", GetLastError()); // Fail, error code 1814
```

The file is a 32x16 bmp file saved as "bitmap1.bmp" as a resource created within VS.

As it finds the resource in the first line, I think it's compiled into the binary fine.

Comment: this is because you use `NULL` as first parameter to [ImageList_LoadImage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761557(v=vs.85).aspx) *hi* - simply reread documentation. you need `ImageList_LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(NULL), ..`

Comment: Thank you that worked. Sorry I missed that from the docs

Answer (score 3):

I assume that with this call

```
auto hImageList = ::ImageList_LoadImage(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP1), 16, 2, CLR_DEFAULT, IMAGE_BITMAP, 0);
```

You're assuming that the `NULL` value for the `HINSTANCE` will make the function search through the current module. This is not so for this function, according to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761557(v=vs.85).aspx).

To get the `HINSTANCE` of the current module, you can call `GetModuleHandle(NULL)`. Replace the `NULL` in your code with that call and it should work.

```
auto hImageList = ::ImageList_LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP1), 16, 2, CLR_DEFAULT, IMAGE_BITMAP, 0);
```